# why jquery repeat my layout again and again

Tags: jquery

I don't know which of my plugins don't work fine, but I'm confusing why jquery create my layouts again and again !

I haven't any error to post here and I don't know fetch this collision !

my page:

http://www.shadyab.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At file `http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/js/rada.js` ( line 84 )

you have code

```
// Append config box / Only for demo purpose
// Uncomment on server mode to enable XHR calls
$.get("skin-config.html", function (data) {
    if (!$('body').hasClass('no-skin-config'))
        $('body').append(data);
});
```

`data` is your html page - so you append your page, that start loading all scripts etc and then in loop

Start of `data`

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ویرایش محتوا</title>

    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/plugins/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/assests/admin/css/style.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You request page at http://www.shadyab.com/nutella/admin/Products/editProductByID/skin-config.html -- if complete html document, so error or in document body or in your logic ( where you append )

Comment: you really saved my time. Big like.